# Creating custom shadows with Robolectric 2.X

Tags: android, robolectric

I am running Robolectric 2.x(2.4) on my project. I have followed the example in the official doc to create a custom shadow of my own class but Robolectric is not using it.

The project is on [GitHub(branch roboMockitoTutorial)](https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/RobolectricSample/tree/roboMockitoTutorial). Here is some pieces of the code:

The class which I try to create shadow(AppUtils):

```
package com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample;

/**
 * Created by jiahao on 2/15/15.
 */
public class AppUtils {

    public AppUtils() {}

    public int generateNumberUsersRandomly() {
        // :)
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The Activity where the class is used:

```
package com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView my_hello_text_view;
    Button mClickMeBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppUtils appUtils = new AppUtils();
        System.out.println("The randomly generated number of users is " + appUtils.generateNumberUsersRandomly());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        my_hello_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_hello_text_view);
        mClickMeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickMeBtn);

        int w = 200, h = 200;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 200, new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Writting in the outputStream " + oneByte);
            }
        });
    }

    public void clickMeBtnPressed(View view) {
        my_hello_text_view.setText(getString(R.string.ok_thanks));
    }
}
```

The shadow class(AppUtilsShadow):

```
package com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample;

import org.robolectric.annotation.Implementation;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements;
import org.robolectric.annotation.RealObject;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView;

/**
 * Created by jiahao on 2/15/15.
 */
@Implements(AppUtils.class)
public class AppUtilsShadow {

    @RealObject
    private AppUtils appUtils;

    public AppUtilsShadow() {}

    // Trying to create the constructor for it.
    public void __constructor__() {}

    @Implementation
    public int generateNumberUsersRandomly() {
        System.out.println("Invoking the real object method");
        return appUtils.generateNumberUsersRandomly();
    }
}
```

The test class:

```
package com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample;

import com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample.MainActivity;
import com.jiahaoliuliu.robolectricsample.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = {AppUtilsShadow.class, MyShadowBitmap.class})
public class MyActivityTest {

  private MainActivity mActivity;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyActivityAppearsAsExpectedInitially() {
    assertThat(mActivity.my_hello_text_view).isVisible();
    assertThat(mActivity.my_hello_text_view).hasText("Hello world!");
    assertThat(mActivity.mClickMeBtn).hasText("Click Me");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catch with Shadows is that they are meant for shadowing Android classes, not all classes. See [documentation](http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/) or even better, the [code](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-2.4/robolectric/src/main/java/org/robolectric/bytecode/Setup.java#L78-L85).

Since AppUtils is not from the Android SDK, your shadow does not get picked up.

This is not a flaw, as far as I can tell, it's an intentional decision by design. Since this is your own class, you have better ways accessible to you for loading up a test class and shouldn't need shadows.

That said, if you really want to use shadows for this, you can create a custom test runner where you override `shouldInstrument` to make it also instrument the classes or packages you're interested in. Then, the code you have above should work. I've never tried this, but you can check [this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/b98ef72e536f4d1d5a713c8d30cd7dd3a6629cad/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/TestRunners.java#L31-L45) out for some sample code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I have implemented it on Robolectric2.4 and 3.0. It seems to work fine. The code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/RobolectricSample/blob/master/app-tests/src/main/java/com/jiahaoliuliu/robolectricsample/RobolectricGradleTestRunner.java